# What is "SoftwareComponent" in Gradle's ivy-publish plugin?

Tags: plugins, gradle, ivy

From Gradle 1.5 was introduced ivy-publish plugin and in it there is a new Interface - SoftwareComponent in the docs is written:

> The simplest way to publish a Gradle project to an Ivy repository is to
>   specify a SoftwareComponent to publish.

So what is SoftwareComponent? What does it consist of - all jars from the build or what? 
Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, two components are available: `components.java` for a Jar, and `components.web` for a War. For more details, see "65.2.1. Publishing a Software Component" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Where is components.web actually defined?

Comment: `components` is shorthand for `project.getComponents()`, which is defined on the `Project` class.

Comment: In the Gradle 2.0 docs, the referenced section seems to be 64.2.1 instead. But that doesn't seem to answer the original question. What *is* a SoftwareComponent? What does it contain? Can we define new ones?

Comment: It's an abstraction for a unit of code that can depend on other units of code. You can't currently define your own software components, but you'll likely be able to in the future.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser is this still valid ? that one cannot define its own component? Which plugin adds components to the project?

Comment: components.java and components.web are introduced by the java/war plugins while custom components can also be declared in recent gradle versions https://docs.gradle.org/3.1/userguide/software_model_extend.html . However this feature is **incubating** and is undergoing constant changes.